# Power reduction

Tags: trigonometry

> Express $$\frac{(1−\cos(2x))(1+\cos(4x))^2}{4(1+\cos(2x))}$$ in terms of cosine, using only first powers.

Per: Andre's suggestion:
\begin{align*}
(1-\cos(2x))(1+\cos(4x))^{2} 
&=1+2\cos(4x)+\cos^{2}(4x)-\cos(2x)-2\cos(2x)\cos(4x)-\cos(2x)\cos^{2}(4x)\\
&=1+2\cos(4x)+\frac{1+\cos(8x)}{2}-\cos(2x)-2\cos(2x)\cos(4x)-\cos(2x)\frac{1+\cos(8x)}{2}
\end{align*}

Then: $2\cos(2x)\cos(4x) = -cos(2x)+\cos(6x)$ & -cos(2x)((1+cos(8x))/2) = -cos(2x)cos^2(4x) = −(−2cos(2x)−cos(6x)−cos(10x))/4

Final answer: (1+2cos(4x)+(1+cos(8x)/2)−cos(2x)-cos(2x)+cos(6x)−(2cos(2x)−cos(6x)−cos(10x))/4)/4+4cos(2x)

Comment: Is the expression $$\frac{(1-\cos(2x))(1+\cos^{2}(4x))}{4(1+\cos(2x))}$$ or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should be: ((1-cos(2x))(1+cos(4x))^2)/4(1+cos(2x))

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried (by editing the post). If you are unsure on how to start, you could always expand the numerator and try to see if you can simplify the powers using double angle formulas and the like.

Comment: Ok, that seems to do the trick: 1+2cos(4x)+cos^(2)(4x)-cos(2x)-2cos(2x)cos(4x)-cos(2x)cos^(2)(4x)=1+2cos(4x)+(1+cos(8x))/(2)-cos(2x)-2cos(2x)cos(4x)-cos(2x)(1+cos(8x))/(2) is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a great start! We can see that there are still some non-linear terms in $\cos$ for which we can use the famous $$\cos(Ax)\cos(Bx)=\frac{1}{2}[\cos[(A-B)x]+\cos[(A+B)x].$$ As I said though, it is better if you edit the post to include your attempt there (I can help you with the formatting of the math if you do so) because vital information, like your attempt at answering the question, should be contained in the post itself.

Comment: Ok, now should I multiply by 2 to clear denominators?

Comment: @NuclearWinter You shouldn't be multiplying by 2 because then the resulting expression will not be equivalent. You don't need to clear the denominators, just finish applying the product-to-sum identity Andre provided wherever relevant and you should be finished.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Ok, I reached an answer.  I have some confidence, but could you confirm?

Comment: @AlanAbraham Ok, I reached an answer. I have some confidence, but could you confirm?

Comment: @NuclearWinter To check your answer, you could just graph the original expression and your own expression

Comment: Of you have found an answer to your question then please post it as answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

$\frac{6-10cos(2x)+8cos(4x)-5cos(6x)+2cos(8x)-cos(10x)}{16(1+cos(2x))}$

To reply to Nuclear Winter:

$1+cos(4x)=2cos(2x)^{2}=2(2cos(x)^{2}-1)^{2}$;

$\frac{(1−\cos(2x))(1+\cos(4x))^2}{4(1+\cos(2x))}=$

$\frac{2 sin(x)^{2}.4(2cos(x)^{2}-1)^{4}}{4.2cos(x)^{2}}=$,

$\frac{(1-cos(x))(1+cos(x))(2cos(x)^{2}-1)^{4}}{cos(x)^{2}}$.

Comment: There are a lot of non first powers in your answer

Comment: @miracle173 Where?

Comment: $\cos(x)^2$ is a power of 2

Comment: The final answer doesn't have it...

Comment: @giuseppe mancò I graphed your solution and the original, and they match, thank you.  However, if I may ask, how did you get from the original to (2cos(x)2−1)4(1+cos(x))(1−cos(x))/cos(x^2?